# Store the old formula and replace with a new one

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code below to track the changes on a sheet based on who made the change, the date/time, the old value and the new value. However, some cells contain formulas and whenever a formula is changed, the code replace the formula in the active sheet by the result/output but I would like to keep the formula not have it changed in a value in the active sheet. Also, whenever a formula is changed, i would like to store the old formula and the new formula as well. Thanks a lot!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values     (before UnDo)
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Log  - Inputs - Divisions")
    Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
      'sh.Unprotect "" 'it should be good to protect the sheet
     If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet      Name")

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it   faster)
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
     If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
        TgValue = extractData(Target)
     Else
        TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or  as a string for a single cell)
        boolOne = True
     End If
     Application.EnableEvents = False                                'avoiding to trigger the change event   after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                           'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                            'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
     Application.EnableEvents = True

     Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
     For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
        If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
            sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).Value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.Name)
        End If
     Next r
 
    'sh.Protect ""
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
For Each El In arr
    sh.Range(El(1)).Value = El(0)
Next
End Sub

Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the 
values and the cells address
        For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
            arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 
0)): count = count + 1
        Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Your code calls methods you've not included in your post, so it's difficult to see what we can suggest here.

Comment: It's not full code, there are missing procedure `PutDataBack` and function `ExtractData`. But maybe you just need to use `Target.Formula` instead of `Target.Value`. Of course, you also need to modify the snippets that refer to the case `Target.Count > 1`.

Comment: You should modify the `extractData` and `putDataBack` functions to handle the extraction and restoration of formulas instead of cell values. Please edit your post to share the code.

Comment: Oops sorry, i had forgotten to share the procedures. I just edited the code! thank you to all of you for helping! @TimWilliams

Comment: full code above @MGonet

Comment: Full code above @taller

Answer (score 0):

- Change all `.Value` to `.Formula`
- If cells don't have a formula (which starts with euqal sign), the `Formula` property return its value. That is, it is same as `.Value`.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values     (before UnDo)
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Log  - Inputs - Divisions")
    Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
      'sh.Unprotect "" 'it should be good to protect the sheet
     If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet      Name")

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it   faster)
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
     If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
        TgValue = extractData(Target)
     Else
        TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Formula, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or  as a string for a single cell)
        boolOne = True
     End If
     Application.EnableEvents = False                                'avoiding to trigger the change event   after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                           'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                            'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
     Application.EnableEvents = True

     Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
     For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
        If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
            sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).Formula = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.Name)
        End If
     Next r
 
    'sh.Protect ""
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
For Each El In arr
    sh.Range(El(1)).Formula = El(0)
Next
End Sub

Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
        For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
            arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Formula, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
        Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @taller! this runs smoothly :)